# How to compare two test results in two different Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have two different jobs setup in Jenkins. I need to compare the total test cases in both Jenkins jobs. Kindly could you please let me know if there is a way to do that?

I can manually check by logging in to each job and collecting data. But I need to find an automated way. I searched many articles in the Internet but I could not find any which my problem can be resolved.

Comment: What kind of test case results are the jobs creating? Based on the test/report file types there might be plugins or functionality. For example junit tests can show which test cases started failing from the last build to the next or continued failing, but other test frameworks might not have that functionality in Jenkins. So knowing what test framework you are using will help us to be able to better answer your question :)

Comment: Including some in-house built frameworks, there are a couple of other frameworks that are also used. We can see the results under the Results section and need to compare those.
Thanks a lot in advanced.